# SVG to PNG in PHP results wrong

Tags: php, svg, png, imagick

I am trying to convert a SVG image code into PNG image for response.
But somehow (I dont know why, but results in my local(mac) is okay, but in Ubuntu 20.0 its respond wrong) Image is not that i expect.

Heres the results:

Orignial SVG:

[image]

Resulted at Ubuntu:

[image]

Heres my code:

```
        $image = new \Imagick();
        $image->readImageBlob($mySvgImage);
        $image->setImageFormat("png32");
```

Comment: What is `Multiavatar`? What is in `$string`? Have you tried to reproduce the problem with a simpler SVG? If so, you could [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; without that, it's going to be hard for anyone to do anything other than guess at what your problem might be. Checking the installed version of ImageMagick on each server would also be helpful.

Comment: @IMSoP better? its just a library that gives svg avatar. Check this out: https://multiavatar.com/

Comment: Not really - how are we supposed to know what's going on, when we don't know what's in the SVG? Maybe the library is generating broken SVGs; maybe it's using some advanced SVG feature; it would all be complete guesswork. That's why trying to make a [mcve] is so important.

Comment: @IMSoP This is the svg i got https://api.multiavatar.com/salam

Comment: Those lines are indeed there, they just have a `style="fill: none"` on them. My recommendation would be to upgrade imagick and/or librsvg and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

According to your screenshot all paths get a stroke applied (unless they have a specific stroke style).
As a workaround you might try to set a default stroke style on the parent svg :

```
<svg stroke="none" stroke-width="0">
```

```html
<style>
  svg {
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 231 231" stroke="none" stroke-width="0">
  <path d="M33.83,33.83a115.5,115.5,0,1,1,0,163.34,115.49,115.49,0,0,1,0-163.34Z" style="fill:#ff7520;" />
  <path d="m115.5 51.75a63.75 63.75 0 0 0-10.5 126.63v14.09a115.5 115.5 0 0 0-53.729 19.027 115.5 115.5 0 0 0 128.46 0 115.5 115.5 0 0 0-53.729-19.029v-14.084a63.75 63.75 0 0 0 53.25-62.881 63.75 63.75 0 0 0-63.65-63.75 63.75 63.75 0 0 0-0.09961 0z" style="fill:#cc9a5c;" />
  <path d="m88.18 194.11c-4.2079 1.021-8.3545 2.2792-12.42 3.7695v26.072a115.5 115.5 0 0 0 79.48 0v-26.072c-4.0858-1.4904-8.2529-2.7486-12.48-3.7695v8.7051c0 9.3888-7.6112 17-17 17h-20.58c-9.3888 0-17-7.6112-17-17v-8.7051z" style="fill:#ff14e4;" />
  <path d="m43.891 77.836c-5.1124 28.237 2.1347 61.004 24.792 81.332-6.2362-12.503-9.5362-33.948-9.4887-45.458-0.50203-37.473 41.439-46.335 56.149-17.614 18.8-31.2 52.825-16.872 54.062 13.714 0.56018 13.844-0.43568 25.598-7.0962 48.966 18.372-12.47 28.012-53.959 23.545-80.941-47.486-2.2552-94.831-2.5724-141.96 0z" style="fill:#FFC600;" />
  <path d="m111.26 12.782c-18.508 0.0791-32.594 3.6163-32.594 3.6163 24.513 5.6002 32.807 10.504 31.743 19.835-0.87227 9.702-11.092 10.875-20.811 11.554-5.2548 0.36414-10.949 0.71523-16.391 1.7525-11.862 2.2818-19.946 4.3736-24.447 11.956-1.7012 2.8662-3.7945 10.428-4.8689 16.34h141.96c-5.7242-38.563-32.557-65.073-74.595-65.054z" style="fill:none;" />
  <path d="m73.292 44.77c-11.788 2.2816-18.923 5.5444-23.394 13.126-2.8484 6.7586-4.8454 13.238-6.0072 19.939h141.96c-1.9772-14.576-6.8677-28.248-19.277-32.098-28.834-6.3308-63.774-6.3553-93.285-0.96761z" style="fill:#FFC600;" />
  <path d="m165.95 35.642c-11.178 21.829-91.89 19.36-103.98 2.3011-9.703 12.267-15.605 25.883-18.079 39.892h141.96c-3.0096-17.158-9.7424-32.688-19.902-42.193z" style="fill:none;" />
  <path d="m145.38 95.628c-5.1601 2.2597-11.03 2.2597-16.19 0m-47.29 1.75c5.1755-2.2694 11.065-2.2694 16.24 0" style="fill:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:5.9998px;stroke:#795548;" />
  <path d="m90.016 106.28c-4.4506-0.0105-6.6902 5.3657-3.5508 8.5195 3.1394 3.1539 8.5252 0.93887 8.5352-3.5117 0.0063-2.7522-2.2204-4.9898-4.9727-4.9961l-0.011719-0.01172zm47.281 0c-4.4506-0.0105-6.6902 5.3657-3.5508 8.5195 3.1394 3.1539 8.5252 0.93887 8.5352-3.5117 6e-3 -2.7522-2.2204-4.9898-4.9727-4.9961l-0.01171-0.01172z" style="fill:#000;" />
  <path d="m100.35 143.85a7.67 7.67 0 0 0 7.58 7.7v0a7.66 7.66 0 0 0 7.57-7.7 7.66 7.66 0 0 0 7.57 7.7v0a7.67 7.67 0 0 0 7.58-7.7" style="fill:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:6.3998px;stroke:#6e1c1c;" />
</svg>


<h3>Ubuntu rendering – simulated by strokes</h3>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 231 231" stroke="#000">
  <path d="M33.83,33.83a115.5,115.5,0,1,1,0,163.34,115.49,115.49,0,0,1,0-163.34Z" style="fill:#ff7520;" />
  <path d="m115.5 51.75a63.75 63.75 0 0 0-10.5 126.63v14.09a115.5 115.5 0 0 0-53.729 19.027 115.5 115.5 0 0 0 128.46 0 115.5 115.5 0 0 0-53.729-19.029v-14.084a63.75 63.75 0 0 0 53.25-62.881 63.75 63.75 0 0 0-63.65-63.75 63.75 63.75 0 0 0-0.09961 0z" style="fill:#cc9a5c;" />
  <path d="m88.18 194.11c-4.2079 1.021-8.3545 2.2792-12.42 3.7695v26.072a115.5 115.5 0 0 0 79.48 0v-26.072c-4.0858-1.4904-8.2529-2.7486-12.48-3.7695v8.7051c0 9.3888-7.6112 17-17 17h-20.58c-9.3888 0-17-7.6112-17-17v-8.7051z" style="fill:#ff14e4;" />
  <path d="m43.891 77.836c-5.1124 28.237 2.1347 61.004 24.792 81.332-6.2362-12.503-9.5362-33.948-9.4887-45.458-0.50203-37.473 41.439-46.335 56.149-17.614 18.8-31.2 52.825-16.872 54.062 13.714 0.56018 13.844-0.43568 25.598-7.0962 48.966 18.372-12.47 28.012-53.959 23.545-80.941-47.486-2.2552-94.831-2.5724-141.96 0z" style="fill:#FFC600;" />
  <path d="m111.26 12.782c-18.508 0.0791-32.594 3.6163-32.594 3.6163 24.513 5.6002 32.807 10.504 31.743 19.835-0.87227 9.702-11.092 10.875-20.811 11.554-5.2548 0.36414-10.949 0.71523-16.391 1.7525-11.862 2.2818-19.946 4.3736-24.447 11.956-1.7012 2.8662-3.7945 10.428-4.8689 16.34h141.96c-5.7242-38.563-32.557-65.073-74.595-65.054z" style="fill:none;" />
  <path d="m73.292 44.77c-11.788 2.2816-18.923 5.5444-23.394 13.126-2.8484 6.7586-4.8454 13.238-6.0072 19.939h141.96c-1.9772-14.576-6.8677-28.248-19.277-32.098-28.834-6.3308-63.774-6.3553-93.285-0.96761z" style="fill:#FFC600;" />
  <path d="m165.95 35.642c-11.178 21.829-91.89 19.36-103.98 2.3011-9.703 12.267-15.605 25.883-18.079 39.892h141.96c-3.0096-17.158-9.7424-32.688-19.902-42.193z" style="fill:none;" />
  <path d="m145.38 95.628c-5.1601 2.2597-11.03 2.2597-16.19 0m-47.29 1.75c5.1755-2.2694 11.065-2.2694 16.24 0" style="fill:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:5.9998px;stroke:#795548;" />
  <path d="m90.016 106.28c-4.4506-0.0105-6.6902 5.3657-3.5508 8.5195 3.1394 3.1539 8.5252 0.93887 8.5352-3.5117 0.0063-2.7522-2.2204-4.9898-4.9727-4.9961l-0.011719-0.01172zm47.281 0c-4.4506-0.0105-6.6902 5.3657-3.5508 8.5195 3.1394 3.1539 8.5252 0.93887 8.5352-3.5117 6e-3 -2.7522-2.2204-4.9898-4.9727-4.9961l-0.01171-0.01172z" style="fill:#000;" />
  <path d="m100.35 143.85a7.67 7.67 0 0 0 7.58 7.7v0a7.66 7.66 0 0 0 7.57-7.7 7.66 7.66 0 0 0 7.57 7.7v0a7.67 7.67 0 0 0 7.58-7.7" style="fill:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:6.3998px;stroke:#6e1c1c;" />
</svg>
```